Magento-Cloud: What does this command will do: magento-cloud environment: branch <environment-name> <parent-environment-id>?
If I run this command on Magento cloud cli what will happen after running this command?
magento-cloud environment: branch <environment-name> <parent-environment-id>


The magento-cloud command magento-cloud environment:branch is used to create a new environment branch and active it.
If you create a branch using Git command instead of the magento-cloud CLI, it will only checkout the Git branch and will not be “activated”. This means it will not automatically build when you push changes to the remote environment.
You can refer to the official documentation at https://experienceleague.adobe.com/en/docs/commerce-cloud-service/user-guide/dev-tools/cloud-cli/cloud-cli-overview
Tip: Utilize Google Search to find the answer to a question like this.

will the newly created brach inherit db and code?
